# What is a good example to differentiate between fileprivate and private in Swift3

Tags: swift, swift3, private, access-control, access-specifier

This [article](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160328/013664.html) has been helpful in understanding the new access specifiers in `Swift 3`.  It also gives some examples of different usages of `fileprivate` and `private`.

My question is - isn't using `fileprivate` on a function that is going to be used only in this file the same as using `private`?

Answer (score 298, accepted):

`fileprivate` is now what `private` used to be in earlier
Swift releases: accessible from
the same source file. A declaration marked as `private` can now only be accessed within the lexical scope it is declared in. 
So `private` is more restrictive than `fileprivate`.

As of **Swift 4,** private declarations inside a type are accessible to extensions of the same type if the extension is defined in the same source file.

Example (all in one source file):

```
class A {
    private func foo() {}
    fileprivate func bar() {}

    func baz() {
        foo()
        bar()
    }
}

extension A {
    func test() {
        foo() // Swift 3: error: use of unresolved identifier 'foo'
              // Swift 4: no error because extension is in same source file
        bar()
    }
}

let a = A()
a.foo() // error: 'foo' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level
a.bar()
```

- The private `foo` method is accessible only within the scope of 
  the `class A { ... }` definition. It is not even accessible from
  an extension to the type (in Swift 3, see the second note below for 
  changes in Swift 4).
- The file-private `bar` method is accessible from the same source file.

*Notes:*

1. The proposal [SE-0159 – Fix Private Access Levels](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0159-fix-private-access-levels.md) suggested to revert to the Swift 2 semantics in Swift 4. After a lengthy and controversial discussion on the swift-evolution mailing list, the proposal was [rejected](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20170403/034902.html).
2. The proposal [SE-0169 – Improve Interaction Between private Declarations and Extensions](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0169-improve-interaction-between-private-declarations-and-extensions.md) suggests to make `private`
   declarations inside a type accessible to extensions of the same type
   if the extension is defined in the *same source file.*
   This proposal was accepted and implemented in Swift 4.

Comment: If you're converting code automatically from Swift 2 to 3, Xcode will turn `private` into `fileprivate`. However, if you have the luxury of doing it by hand, you can often benefit from leaving `private` as `private`... if it compiles, all good.

Comment: @DanielLarsson: Re your edit suggestions: *Both* comments apply to the `foo()` call.

Answer (score 89):

I just draw a diagram about **private**, **fileprivate**, **open** and **public**

Hope it can quickly help you , for text description please refer to **Martin R** 's answer

**[ Update Swift 4, 5 ]**

[image]

Comment: watch out, `fileprivate` is not linked to the extension but to the file (writing an extension of class A in another file will not permit the use of `fileprivate` members)

Comment: This seems incorrect. You are missing the key point. You have to differentiate between classes that are inside the same module and that are in different modules. If they are in different modules then `public` won't allow you to inherit, therefore the 3rd image is incorrect. Also, you can always put an extension to any class if you can see it. Explaining visibility on extensions is not a very good idea then.

Comment: Indeed, I should mention my diagram works only on the same module, therefore 3rd image I just want user quickly understand **fileprivate** only works on the same file.

Answer (score 9):

**Updated for Swift 5**

**Private** vs **FilePrivate**

*For better clarity paste the code snippet in Playground*

```
class Sum1 {
    let a: Int!
    let b: Int!
    private var result: Int?
    fileprivate var resultt: Int?

    init(a : Int, b: Int) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }

    func sum(){
        result = a + b
        print(result as! Int)
    }
}

let aObj = Sum1.init(a: 10, b: 20)
aObj.sum()
aObj.resultt //File Private Accessible as inside same swift file
aObj.result //Private varaible will not be accessible outside its definition except extensions

extension Sum1{

    func testing() {

        // Both private and fileprivate accessible in extensions
        print(result)
        print(resultt)
    }
}

//If SUM2 class is created in same file as Sum1 ---
class Sum2{

    func test(){

        let aSum1 = Sum1.init(a: 2, b: 2)
        // Only file private accessible
        aSum1.resultt

    }
}
```

**Note**: Outside of Swift file both private and fileprivate are not accessible.

Answer (score 6):

A practical rule of thumb is that you use private for variables, constants, inner structs and classes that are used only inside the declaration of your class / struct.  You use fileprivate for things that are used inside of your extensions within the same file as your class/struct but outside of their defining curly braces (ie. their lexical scope).

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
        //This is not used outside of class Viewcontroller
        private var titleText = "Demo"
        //This gets used in the extension
        fileprivate var list = [String]()
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            navigationItem.title = titleText
        }
    }

    extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return list.count
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 4.0, Private is now accessible in extension but within same file. If you declare/define extension in other file, then your private variable will not be accessible to your extension**

**File Private**

File-private access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining source file. Use file-private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality when those details are used within an entire file.

*Syntax:* `fileprivate <var type> <variable name>`

*Example:* `fileprivate class SomeFilePrivateClass {}`

**Private**

Private access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration, and to extensions of that **declaration that are in the same file**. Use private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality when those details are used only within a single declaration.

*Syntax:* `private <var type> <variable name>`

*Example:* `private class SomePrivateClass {}`

Here is more detail about all access levels: [Swift - Access Levels](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

*Look at this images:*

**File:** ViewController.swift

Here extension and view controller both are in same file, hence private variable `testPrivateAccessLevel` is accessible in extension

[image]

**File:** TestFile.swift

Here extension and view controller both are in different files, hence private variable `testPrivateAccessLevel` is not accessible in extension.

[image]

[image]

Here class `ViewController2` is a subclass of `ViewController` and both are in same file. Here private variable `testPrivateAccessLevel` is not accessible in Subclass but fileprivate is accessible in subclass.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Although @MartinR's and @StephenChen's answer are perfect, **Swift 4** changes things a little bit.

**Private** is now considered as private to a class in which it is declared and also to its extensions.

**FilePrivate** is considered to be private in that file be it a class in which the variable is defined, it's extension, or any other classes defined in that same file.

Answer (score 4):

**filePrivate** -  access controll level is within the file.

**case 1**: If we create extension with in same class file and try to access fileprivate function or fileprivate property in its extension - access allowed
**case 2**: If we create a extension of class in new file - And now try to access fileprivate function or fileprivate property - access not allowed

**private** - access control level is with in lexical scope

**case 1**: If property or function is declared as private in class - then scope is by default the class.
**case 2**: if private instance is declared with in function body - then scope of instance is limited to function body.

Answer (score 4):

This is the explanation for swift 4. For swift 3, the difference is the private. swift 3 private cannot be accessed by its extension, only Class A itself can access.

[image]
After swift 4, fileprivate becomes a bit redundant, because person normally will not define the subclass in the same file. Private should be enough for most cases.

Answer (score 3):

In the following example, language constructs modified by `private` and `fileprivate` seem to behave identically:

```
fileprivate func fact(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1
    } else {
        return n * fact(n - 1)
    }
}

private func gauss(_ n: Int) -> Int {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0
    } else {
        return n + gauss(n - 1)
    }
}

print(fact(0))
print(fact(5))
print(fact(3))

print(gauss(10))
print(gauss(9))
```

This is according to intuition, I guess. But, is there any exception?

Kindest regards.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Privacy {

    fileprivate(set) var pu:Int {
        get {
            return self.pr
        }
        set {
            self.pr = newValue
        }
    }
    private var pr:Int = 0
    fileprivate var fp:Int = 0


    func ex() {
        print("\(self.pu) == \(self.pr) and not \(self.fp)")
    }
}


extension Privacy {

    func ex2() {
        self.pu = 5
        self.ex()
    }

}
```

I like this because it is super simple for ivars.

Try changing fileprivate to private (and vice versa) and see what happens on compile...