# Distinction between private and fileprivate top-level classes

Tags: swift, swift3, access-control

In Swift 3, what exactly is the difference in access control between

```
private class Foo { }
```

and

```
fileprivate class Bar { }
```

assuming both are top-level classes, that is, they are placed directly into a file rather than nested in some other construct?

Comment: Related: [private vs. fileprivate on declaring global variables/consts in Swift3?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39739813/2976878) – there is no difference in the case you propose.

Comment: What about with implicitly-scoped variables inside the class? Do either of these affect their scopes?  According to the docs, it should, but according to real-world testing, it doesn't. In both cases they are fileprivate.  From the docs: If you define a type’s access level as private or file private, the default access level of its members will also be private or file private.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in your case. The only time that `fileprivate` differs from `private` is inside a class, struct, or protocol.

Comment: That's strange. I wonder why they just don't allow `private` on top-level entities.

Comment: @Ethcad There are other degenerate cases for access control levels, see [this post](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20160926/003474.html) from the mailing list discussion on the matter. Making a special exception for the particular case of top-level entities is unnecessary IMO.