# What's the access level of a case within a private enumeration

Tags: swift

I read the document about Swift 5.1 from swift.org and have some questions about access level in enumeration.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html#ID14

In the document, it says:

> The individual cases of an enumeration automatically receive the same access level as the enumeration they belong to.

```swift
private enum SomePrivateEnum {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}

private class SomePrivateClass {
    private var somePrivateProperty = 0
}


// work
print(SomePrivateEnum.one)

// error: 'somePrivateProperty' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level
print(SomePrivateClass().somePrivateProperty)
```

According to the document, if I have a `private` enum, then all cases should receive `private` access level. The question is, why can I access the private case outside the enum declaration ? This behavior is different from `Class`.

Comment: At the top level of a file, `private` is effectively `fileprivate`, therefore both the enum and its cases are only accessible within the file that defined it. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43503274/2976878.

Comment: @Hamish I assume the point to take home here is that while an enumeration groups a number of values together it is not a scope of its own like a struct or class or a file?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson An enum is a scope, the documentation is just a bit misleading. When it says "receive the same access level as" what it really means is "is accessible within the same scope as". It's just like if you had written `private class SomePrivateClass { var someProperty = 0 }` – `someProperty` is accessible anywhere `SomePrivateClass` is, which in this case is anywhere within the file that defined it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code is completely artificial, as it would not even compile except in a playground — and in a playground the concepts of privacy are more or less meaningless. Test only within a real project.

When you do, you will have something like this:

```
private enum SomePrivateEnum {
    case one
    case two
    case three
}
private class SomePrivateClass {
    private var somePrivateProperty = 0
}
class ViewController : UIViewController {
    func test() {
        print(SomePrivateEnum.one)
        print(SomePrivateClass().somePrivateProperty)
    }
}
```

Now that we've established that, we can proceed to what's wrong with your test itself, namely that you are comparing apples with oranges. Here's the parallelism:

```
    print(SomePrivateEnum.one) // ok
    print(SomePrivateClass()) // ok
```

So `private` for SomePrivateEnum and `private` for SomePrivateClass mean the same thing, namely: "private *within this file*". This code is in the same file so it can see both SomePrivateEnum and SomePrivateClass. (As the docs tell you, code that can see SomePrivateEnum can see `SomePrivateEnum.one`, and vice versa. So we are now comparing apples with apples.)

But `private` for `somePrivateProperty` means *something else*. It means "private *within this type*". So only code inside SomePrivateClass can see `somePrivateProperty`. This code is not inside SomePrivateClass, so it can't see that property.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `private` declarations inside current context.
for example, if you wrap enum with other context - it will not be accessible same way as property inside `SomePrivateClass`.

i.e. this will be inaccessible:

```swift
struct Foo {
    private enum SomePrivateEnum {
        case one
        case two
        case three
    }
}
print(Foo.SomePrivateEnum.one)
```

and this will be:

```swift
private class SomePrivateClass {
    var somePrivateProperty = 0
}
print(SomePrivateClass().somePrivateProperty)
```