# What is default access modifier for private class property in swift 5.0?

Tags: swift

As per swift documentation, ***If you define a type’s access level as private or file private, the default access level of its members will also be private or file private***

I had created a sample code to analyse above statement using Swift 5.0

```
private class Profile {
    var name: String?
    //By default name should have private access level implicitly
}

private class Person {
    private var name: String?
    //name should have private access level explicitly
}

func gobalTestFunction() {
    let profile = Profile()
    let profileName = profile.name
    //This does not give any error and name is accessible here

    let person = Person()
    let personName = person.name
    //This gives error 'name' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level
}
```

**Expected Result:**

While creating profileName there should be an error similar to the error which occur while creating personName

```
'name' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level
```

**Actual Result:**

While creating personName error occurs but while creating profileName no error encountered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/a/43504968 –   A top-level `private` class is actually `fileprivate`.

Answer (score 3):

- To make a class accessible within target/framework and not outside
  that, you can use default internal access modifier.
- And if you want to make the class accessible within the file, you can
  use fileprivate access modifier.

  In short, Making a class private at top-level does not make sense. And it's actually file private.

  Thanks @Martin R for your useful comment.