# If Swift creates a private type of instance, doesn't the initializer have an implicit private access level?

Tags: swift

```
private struct A {
    private init() {}
}

private struct B {
    var a = A() // compile error ⚠️
}
```

This code is explicitly a private init, so I understand that B cannot create an A instance.
But...

```
private struct A {
}

private struct B {
    var a = A() // compile OK ✅
}
```

If A is a private type, this code is implicitly a private init without implementing the initializer, so how can B create an instance of A?

Is there anything I'm missing from Swift?

Comment: Hint: private to what?

Comment: @matt
I know, Private access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration, and to extensions of that declaration that are in the same file.

My question is why there is a difference between explicit and implicit private init.   

Shouldn't it not be called even if it's implicitly private init?

Comment: Let me put the hint a different way. Does `private` mean the same thing for a struct that it means for a method of that struct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Default Initialisers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/accesscontrol#Default-Initializers) section of the Swift Guide:

> A default initializer has the same access level as the type it initializes, unless that type is defined as `public`.

"Same access level" doesn't just mean "copying" whatever access modifier the struct has, to the initialiser. It means that the initialiser is accessible wherever you can access the struct.

The struct `A` is private, meaning that it can only be [accessed within its enclosing file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43054774/5133585) (assuming `A` is declared at the top-level). `B` is in the same file, so it can access `A`. And because `B` can access `A`, it can also access `A.init`.

Also consider the case where `A` and `B` are in another struct:

```
struct Outer {
    private struct A {
        
    }

    private struct B {
        var a = A() // also compiles
    }
}
```

`A` can only be accessed within `Outer`. `B` is inside `Outer`, so it can access `A`. Since `A.init` has the "same access level" as `A`, `B` can also access `A.init`.

Note that this is only the case for *default initialisers*. If you add an uninitialised property inside `A`, it loses the *default initialiser*, and gains a [*memberwise initialiser*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/accesscontrol#Default-Memberwise-Initializers-for-Structure-Types) instead,

> The default memberwise initializer for a structure type is considered private if any of the structure’s stored properties are private.

Note that the phrase "same access level" is not used here. You can only access the memberwise `init` inside `A`, if `A` has a `private` property.

```
private struct A {
    private var x: Int
}

private struct B {
    var a = A(x: 10) // error
}
```

Comment: I understand exactly.
Thank you!

Comment: @chickensoup If you think an answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

In your first case, the initializer for A is explicitly declared private:

```swift
private struct A {
    private init() {}
}
```

So in this case, it is clear that `B` cannot create an instance of `A`.

In the second case, `A` has an implicit initializer, which is equivalent to:

```swift
private struct A {
    init() {} // not private any more
}
```

So if `B` is able to see `A`, which it can in both your examples, this explains why case 2 works.