# Difference between fileprivate and private extension?

Tags: swift3, swift4, access-control, access-modifiers, access-levels

**Swift 3.0**

I know that `fileprivate` access level modifier limited using of function/property to source file where it was declared and `private` - limited to lexical scope where was declared. But it seems that this rule not apply for extensions. E.G. this code is valid:

```
class Foo {
}

fileprivate extension Foo {
    var aa: Int {
        return aaa + 10
    }
}

private extension Foo {
    var aaa: Int {
        return 20
    }
}
```

Can someone help me figured out difference between them? Thanks.

**Swift 4.0**

`private` is now accessible in extension but within same file. If you declare/define extension in other file, then your private variable will not be accessible to your extension.

`fileprivate` is accessible within same file.

Comment: Hmm... I wonder if it's because the scope of the extension IS the file? If you declared the vars as fileprivate and private instead of the extension then this wouldn't work.

Comment: @Fogmeister You are right, if add access modifier to variables, this will not work. Probably, Apple did it, because private extension will not make any sense, i mean everything declared in private extension will be visible only there.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739813/private-vs-fileprivate-on-declaring-global-variables-consts-in-swift3, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43054774/distinction-between-private-and-fileprivate-top-level-classes.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The difference only crops up when we are talking about type members. `private` will restrict access to other methods within the same type definition, while `fileprivate` things are accessible by anything that lives in the same `.swift` file.

For things that live at the top level (outside of a type definition), `private` and `fileprivate` *do exactly the same thing*. So when you write

```
fileprivate extension Foo 
{
    var aa: Int 
    {
        return aaa + 10
    }
}

private extension Foo 
{
    var aaa: Int 
    {
        return 20
    }
}
```

You really wrote

```
fileprivate extension Foo 
{
    var aa: Int 
    {
        return aaa + 10
    }
}

fileprivate extension Foo 
{
    var aaa: Int 
    {
        return 20
    }
}
```

Ultimately, the two extensions on the same protocol get resolved by the compiler into a single extension.

```
fileprivate extension Foo 
{
    var aa: Int 
    {
        return aaa + 10
    }
    var aaa: Int 
    {
        return 20
    }
}
```

If you think think having two keywords like this is [stupid](https://twitter.com/slava_pestov/status/849858472476786688), some Swift architects  [agree with you](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0159-fix-private-access-levels.md). I believe some style guides recommend you only bother using the `public` and `private` access modifiers (as well as the `internal` modifier, but that one is by default) because, in general, restricting things on a per-file basis, as opposed to a per-module or per-type basis is not particularly useful.

If you must use the `fileprivate` modifier, then never use the `private` modifier outside of a type scope. It’s confusing (since the `private` in that context “really” means `fileprivate`) and makes your code harder to read.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean by:  "The difference only crops up when we are talking about type members". Additionally not sure how you addressed the actual question, didn't you show a different scenario?

Comment: @Honey An extension is not a type member, it is declared at the top level. That is why the `private` modifier is really a `fileprivate` modifier spelled differently.

Answer (score 5):

> With Swift 4.0, scope of `private` and `fileprivate` is extended. 
> **Private is now accessible within same file, outside actual class/extension. If you declare/define your extension in other file, then your private variable will not be accessible at that time fileprivate will work**

**File Private**

File-private access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining source file. Use file-private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality when those details are used within an entire file.

*Syntax:* `fileprivate <var type> <variable name>`

*Example:* `fileprivate class SomeFilePrivateClass {}`

**Private**

Private access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration, and to extensions of that **declaration that are in the same file**. Use private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality when those details are used only within a single declaration.

*Syntax:* `private <var type> <variable name>`

*Example:* `private class SomePrivateClass {}`

Here is more detail about all access levels: [Swift - Access Levels](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

Answer (score -1):

Private access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration, and to **extensions of that declaration that are in the same file**.

Private extension and filePrivate extension are acting almost the same on the same file.

```
// Fruite.Swift

struct Fruite {
    let name: String
}
```

---

```
// FruiteTests.Swift

func testSomeThing() {
    let fruite = Fruite()
    let privateDate = fruite.expiryDate_Private // ✅
    let filePrivateDate = fruite.expiryDate_filePrivate // ✅
    
    // both are accessible
}
private extension Fruite {
    var expiryDate_Private : Date {
        return Date()
    }
}

fileprivate extension Fruite {
    var expiryDate_filePrivate: Date {
        return Date()
    }
}
```