# private Helper class with public static func access modifier

Tags: swift, xcode, xctestcase

I think I probably have some blind spot.  The following code in test target actually works that I thought it should not: (MyHelper is private already, but the caller still can use myHelperFunc())

```
// both MyClass and MyHelper are in the same file

class MyClass: XCTestCase {
    func testDoWork() {
        MyHelper.myHelperFunc()
    } 
}

private class MyHelper {
    static func myHelperFunc() -> String {
        return "something"
    } 
}
```

If I move the code to main target (delete the XCTestCase), compiler immediately flag MyHelper is not accessible that seems the right behavior?  Is there something specific for test target that I missed?

Answer (score 0):

`private` at file scope is equivalent to `fileprivate`.

`@testable import` makes `internal` code accessible to a test target.

Comment: private at file scope may not be the same as fileprivate if there are more than one class in the same file.  That is the key difference between private and fileprivate isn't it?  At least for the main target based on my understanding and verified in the main target.  still confused :-(

Comment: No. [`private` means `scope-private`. If that scope is the file, then `private` *is* `fileprivate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287220/difference-between-fileprivate-and-private-extension). I can't tell what you're thinking is going on, which is not going on, but it's something that is not going on! Please edit with more details if you're still confused.

Answer (score 0):

[Access Levels](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AccessControl.html#ID5) in The Swift Programming Language explains how `private` works:

> *Private* access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration, and to extensions of that declaration that are in the same file.

"The enclosing declaration" of MyHelper is "the file." This is perhaps a bit more clearly stated in the [Declaration Modifiers](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID381) section of the Swift Language Reference:

> private
>
> Apply this modifier to a declaration to indicate the declaration can be accessed only by code within the declaration’s immediate enclosing scope.

Again, the "enclosing scope" of MyHelper is the file. If MyHelper were enclosed in some other class, then it would be limited to that scope rather than the whole file:

```
// Things change if MyHelper has a different enclosing scope than MyClass.
class MyClass {
    func testDoWork() {
        MyHelper.myHelperFunc() // Cannot find 'MyHelper' in scope
    }
}

class C {
    // MyClass can't access C.MyHelper now.
    private class MyHelper {
        static func myHelperFunc() -> String {
            return "something"
        }
    }
}
```

In your example, `myHelperFunc()` has no annotation, so it initially receives the default level of `internal`. This is noted in Access Levels again:

> Default Access Levels
>
> All entities in your code (with a few specific exceptions, as described later in this chapter) have a default access level of internal if you don’t specify an explicit access level yourself.

However, as noted in "Guiding Principle of Access Levels:"

> No entity can be defined in terms of another entity that has a lower (more restrictive) access level.

It is not allowed for `MyHelper.myHelperFunc()` to have a broader access level than its encoding type (MyHelper), so it's limited to file scope (which is effectively the same as `fileprivate`).