# Swift 3 convertor added fileprivate func

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

When I run the swift convertor to convert to v3 this got added to one of my VCs'

```
    fileprivate func < <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
      switch (lhs, rhs) {
      case let (l?, r?):
        return l < r
      case (nil, _?):
        return true
      default:
        return false
      }
    }
class MyViewcontroller:UIViewController
```

So why did this function get added?

Comment: Access modifier in Swift 3 http://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-3-access-controls/?utm_campaign=This%2BWeek%2Bin%2BSwift&utm_medium=email&utm_source=This_Week_in_Swift_104

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan Sorry I edited my question, what I wonder is why the migrator added this?

Comment: The linked-to Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39251005/strange-generic-function-appear-in-view-controller-after-converting-to-swift-3 should answer that question.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask about "fileprivate" keywork, already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027250/what-is-a-good-example-to-differentiate-between-fileprivate-and-private-in-swift).

**fileprivate** allows class fields to be accessed from current file, while **private** doesn't, even in case of an extension.

Comment: Sorry I edited my question, what I wonder is why the migrator added this?

Comment: So that your code is still valid. You have optionals comparison which are no longer supported https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0121-remove-optional-comparison-operators.md