# Why does Swift allow leakage of super class member's functionality via a sub class? Is Swift inheritance broken?

Tags: swift, inheritance

I tried this Swift code in XCode.

**File1.swift(Non-Main File):**

```
class A {
    fileprivate func myFun() {
        print("A myFun")
    }
}

class B: A {
    override internal func myFun() {
        super.myFun()
        print("B myFun")
    }
}
```

To note:

1. 'A' does not provide access to 'myFun' to an object made outside of File1.
2. 'B' subclasses A and overrides 'myFun' with an internal access specifier.

**main.swift**

```
let s = B()
s.myFun()
```

**Output:**

A myFun

B myFun

Program ended with exit code: 0

To note:

1. I used a subclass(B) to access a part of the superclass(A) which it didn't allow to be accessed.

**Is this behavior intended? If yes then how is this useful?**

Answer (score 0):

You can find an answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027250/what-is-a-good-example-to-differentiate-between-fileprivate-and-private-in-swift).

In short - `fileprivate != private` while `A` and `B` are in the same file.