# How does Class not inherit some variables?

Tags: swift, class, oop

```
class Model {
    let userId: Int
    let username: String
    private let description: String?

    init(userId: Int, username: String, description: String?) {
        self.userId = userId
        self.username = username
        self.description = description
    }
}

class ModelDetail: Model {
    let url: String
    let detail: String
    
    init(url: String, detail: String, userId: Int, username: String, description: String?) {
        self.url = url
        self.detail = detail
        
        super.init(userId: userId, username: username, description: description)
    }
}
```

I prepared this sample code to copy here. I don't want to inherit "description" value from Model class. When I try to something I am getting this error: Missing argument for parameter 'description' in call

Is it possible not to inherit some variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a good example to differentiate between fileprivate and private in Swift3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027250/what-is-a-good-example-to-differentiate-between-fileprivate-and-private-in-swift)

Comment: Your `description` property is optional so why just not ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot not inherit `description`, but you can assign a value `nil` to it, and simply ignore it.

If you can modify `Model`, you can change its `init` to

```
class Model {
    // ...

    init(userId: Int, username: String, description: String? = nil) 
    // ...
}
```

Since description is optional, we set it to `nil` by default, so `ModelDetail` doesn't need to set it at all:

```
class ModelDetail: Model {
    let url: String
    let detail: String

    init(url: String, detail: String, userId: Int, username: String) {
        self.url = url
        self.detail = detail

        super.init(userId: userId, username: username)
    }
}
```

If you cannot change `Model`, then `ModelDetail` can invoke `Model`'s init with `nil` for description:

```
class ModelDetail: Model {
    // ...

    init(url: String, detail: String, userId: Int, username: String) {
        // ...

        super.init(userId: userId, username: username, description: nil)
    }
}
```

If you want to strictly adhere to the inheritance rules (which do not allow for "unused" fields), then you need to separate `description` from the model `ModelDetail` will be inheriting from. I.e.:

- Have a base model, which only has `userId` and `username`
- Both `Model` and `ModelDetail` will inherit from that base model, rather than each other:

```
class BasicModel {
    let userId: Int
    let username: String

    init(userId: Int, username: String) {
        self.userId = userId
        self.username = username
    }
}

class Model: BasicModel {

    private let description: String?

    init(userId: Int, username: String, description: String?) {
        self.description = description
        super.init(userId: userId, username: username)
    }
}

class ModelDetail: BasicModel {
    let url: String
    let detail: String

    init(url: String, detail: String, userId: Int, username: String) {
        self.url = url
        self.detail = detail

        super.init(userId: userId, username: username)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Our api is returning extra value in child model. I used a separate struct for each. I asked to fix the structure, but it seems that I need to think carefully.